# Python - managing package installations between anaconda and base system

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

When I type `python3`, the anaconda version is executed.
I know this because I type which `python3`, in which I get `/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3`.

So sometimes, I use the non-anaconda version with `/usr/bin/python3.8 myProgram.py`.

So now, I am in a position where I want to install a package, with `pip`.

If I type `pip install package`, then my package will be installed in the anaconda version am I correct?

What if I want to install this package on the system version (located in `/usr/bin/python3.8`)?

Comment: You can check `which pip`. Or if you want to be explicit, run pip as a module instead of using the entry point: e.g., `/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/python3 -m pip install <package>`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I solved it thanks to your comments.